# ExpressJs + Sequelize - Infrequently updated object caching

Tags: caching, express, sequelize.js

I'm working on a project where I need to cache objects from the database that are infrequently updated.

How is this as far as synchronicity goes? Could I run into a race condition due to promises, if the view snippet is rendered inside of a promise? Is this acceptable practice, and does this really make sense to do (assume that many objects are cached like this on the server)?

```js
// array to cache objects
var gPopularTags = [];

// in the module init function
module.exports = function(app, models){
    gModels = models;
    updateTopTags();
    setInterval(updateTopTags, 1000 * 3700);

    // some route that makes use of the cached object
    app.get('/', function(req, res){
        res.render('index', {
            tags: gPopularTags
        }
    });
​
};
// outside of the module init, a private function
function updateTopTags() {
    gModels.Tag.findAll({
        where: {
            useCount: {
                $gt: 0
            }
        },
        order: [['useCount', 'DESC']],
        limit: 5
    }).then(function(tags){
        gPopularTags = tags;
    })
}
```

Then the view used with index has the following code dependent on tags. The views are all written in Jade.

```
if tags
    h1 Popular Tags
    div.list-group
        each tag in tags
            a(href="/tag/#{tag.name}").list-group-item= tag.name
                span.badge= tag.useCount
        a(href="/tag").list-group-item More Tags
```